# window.opener.document.getElementById(..) does not work in IE

Tags: javascript

Im trying to open new window from parent window when user choose to print the parent window ,i re-draw the parent page in the new page by using :

```
document.getElementById('demo_tab_info').innerHTML=window.opener.document.getElementById('demo_tab_info').innerHTML;
```

and then i control the element by javascript(hide some and show some of them).
That work fine with Firefox and Chrome ,but it is not with IE,does there an explanation for this? 
also

```
window.print();
```

Does not work with Chrome? Can any one help with these two problems?

Comment: Wouldn't it be much easier to use a print style sheet that hides every thing you don't want to print? That would remove the popup and JavaScript dependency - things that irritate many users.

Comment: actually i need to go with this, i'm just editing on previous work ,so this was the easier choice to go with,please do have any suggestion how to deal with these problems ,since i almost finish the work when suddenly discover these problems, (note:most of my test on Firefox)

Answer (score 0):

As for second question.

Function:

```
window.print()
```

is supported in all major browser (source: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_print.asp)

But it is true that it is not standardized function by W3C (https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM:window.print).